# Test react in Javacript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Given two non-empty integer arrays, determine if the values ​​in the second array are in the same order in the first array.

public boolean isSubsequent(int[] values, int[] sequence)

input example
isSubsequent(new int[]{5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10}, new int[]{1, 6, -1, 10})

exit example
true

Comment: Are the values in the second array unique?

Comment: You should have one loop for the 2nd array, and inside of this loop should have another with the 1st array. The loop of 1st array should start at the next position of last match with 2nd array, and break when match. At the end, should return true if all vaues of 2nd array was matched. This seams to be academic question, and instead of put the solution here, I prefer give you the algorithm. If you need, I can back here to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep a pointer for the second array and iterate over the first array. If the current element in the first array matches the element pointed in the second array, move the pointer forward. If the pointer reaches the end, then some elements in the first array, are in the same order as in the second one.

However, if the values are not unique, then the situation is a bit different :

Array 1 :   -1 5 1 22 25 6 -1 8 10

Array 2 :   1 6 -1 10

Then in that case, it depends on which -1 you are considering.

Comment: This is the same algorithm that I suggest on the comment, but when I commented, I didn't noticed that you already answered the question. The situation about have the "-1" repeated, in my opinon should not be a problem, since the first match of Array2 on Array1 is on index 2, and all previous indexes will be "ignored" for the final result.

Comment: Yeah, @ManuelRomeiro, the point you made is valid, but I just wanted to address the fact that, there was an ambiguity in the question, even though the solution won't change.